# Format numeric data with optional decimals and a comma as decimal separator

Tags: sql-server, formatting, number-formatting

In SQL Server, I've got a table with length and weight data and I need to export it formatted as numeric where the decimals are optionally added, and when there are decimals use a comma instead of a dot as the decimal separator.

The `FORMAT` function is pretty comprehensive but I could only get it to work by also using `REPLACE` which seems a bit hack-y. See example code below.

```
CREATE TABLE #FOLLOWUP (
    [PATID] int,
    [FULENGTE] numeric(5,1),
    [FUGEWICHT] numeric(5,1)
);

insert into #FOLLOWUP (
    [PATID],
    [FULENGTE],
    [FUGEWICHT]
) values
(1001, 175, 78.5),
(1002, 171.5, 87),
(1003, 181, 75),
(1004, 172, 75),
(1005, 176.5, 90),
(1006, 167, 86),
(1007, 170, 66),
(1008, 181, 90);

select
    patid,
    fulengte,
    FORMAT(fulengte, '0.#') as test_1,
    FORMAT(fulengte, '0,#') as test_2,
    FORMAT(fulengte, '#,#') as test_3,
    FORMAT(fulengte, '#.#0,#') as test_4,
    replace(FORMAT(fulengte, '0.#'), '.', ',') as test_hack
from
    #FOLLOWUP
```

Gives the result below

```
patid  fulengte  test_1  test_2  test_3  test_4  test_hack
1001   175.0     175     175     175     175.00  175
1002   171.5     171.5   172     172     171.50  171,5
1003   181.0     181     181     181     181.00  181
1004   172.0     172     172     172     172.00  172
1005   176.5     176.5   177     177     176.50  176,5
1006   167.0     167     167     167     167.00  167
1007   170.0     170     170     170     170.00  170
1008   181.0     181     181     181     181.00  181
```

Is it possible to use just the `FORMAT` function to format it this way?

Comment: This is really a task for your ETL/presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: You can send an optional "culture" parameter which controls stuff like decimals. For example germans usually use "," instead of ".". See examples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: following @siggermannen suggestion try Spanish culture, something like `FORMAT(fulengte, 'N', 'es-es')`